# Does android developer tools kit include any visual features?

Tags: android, adt

By saying visual I mean if there is a sort of option of seeing how the app might look on your phone while developing it using android developer tools kit downloaded from android website? I hope you got the question clear

Comment: if i understand you are asking about skins .. if yes you must dowload them, to check your app skins layouts, trought Graphical Layout mode select preview all screens

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are building the layout with XML.
While you are developing you can switch between XML view and a graphical view.

[image]

This is in eclipse. Android studio hase something similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is an layout preview in Eclipse where you could choose from a variety of predefined "devices". Also you could add your own.